# Sum text strings on a page

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a numbers spread throughout a page:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {5} consectetur adipisicing elit {2}, 
sed do eiusmod {9} tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Luckily, they are wrapped in curly brackets {}. Using javascript — jQuery is not available —, how do I add these number to return the total: 16 in this case.

Comment: Use a regex to find the numbers, then loop through the matches and add them up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that demonstrates getting the text from the page using [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent), matching a floating point number (this includes whole integers) with exponent (if exists) surrounded in "{" and "}" but not consuming the trailing "}", using a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and then performing a sum of them . During the sum we remove the leading "{" by using [String slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

HTML

```
<div>Lorem ipsum<span>dolor sit amet, </span>{5} consectetur adipisicing<span>elit {2}, sed do eiusmod</span><span>{9} tempor incididunt ut labore </span>et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
```

Javascript

```
var array = document.body.textContent.match(/{[-+]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?(?=\})/g);
var length = array.length;
var i = 0;
var sum = 0;

while (i < length) {
    sum += parseFloat(array[i].slice(1));
    i += 1;
}

console.log(sum);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/CF4mG/)

For interest sake, here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-check-inside-sum/2) of the current (3) answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use eval here...

```
var str = 'Lorem , {5}  elit {2}, sed {9} tempor';

var sum = eval(str.match(/\d+(?=\})/g).join('+'));

/*  returned value: (Number)
16
*/
```

Comment: While `eval` is generally a bad idea, this is a reasonable use of it, especially since the input has gone through sanitisation by only allowing digits.

Comment: While I agree with Kolink, I don't see why you wouldn't just loop over the matches and add them...instead of joining them with `+` and `eval`ing it

Comment: @Ian- It wouldn't matter unless there are a lot of numbers, but it avoids having to convert the strings to numbers individually.

Comment: This will fail if you have a number with a trailing "}" but no leading "{" in the text, I don't know how possible that is in the OPs scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aP5Sz/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {5} consectetur adipisicing elit {2}, sed do eiusmod {9} tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';

var result = str.match(/\{[^}]+\}/g).join('').match(/\d+/g).reduce(function(a,b) {
  return +a + +b;
});

console.log(result); //=>16
```

**Edit:** Check the `gmatch` helper if you want to make it a bit clearer: http://jsbin.com/asufek/1/edit

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce` is not avaiable in older browsers.

Comment: And there's no reason to run 2 regexes, when it can be done with 1.

Comment: @Ian: `match` doesn't capture groups with `g` flag that's why the two regex.

Comment: My point is that there's no need for 2. kennebec's answer has the regex `/\d+(?=\})/g` which works fine.

Comment: I think there is a need for two if done in this manner, kennebecs answer fails if there is a trailing "}" but no leading "{" around the number